# horizontally and vertically align of text with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a string (a sentence) thats approximately 100 characters long and with this example code (it uses textwrap) I can split the string into pieces, and then compute the positions with the textsize method:

```
import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont
import textwrap

sentence='This is a text. Some more text 123. Align me please.'
para=textwrap.wrap(sentence,width=15)

MAX_W,MAX_H=500,800
im = Image.new('RGB', (MAX_W, MAX_H), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Arial.ttf', 36)

current_h=0
for line in para:
    w,h=draw.textsize(line, font=font)
    draw.text(((MAX_W-w)/2, current_h), line, font=font)
    current_h+=h

im.save('test.png')
```

This code is align the text horizontally, but I need the text to be vertically aligned too. How can I do this? The dimensions of my image are 800x500 and I just want to fit a 100 characters long text the perfect way. Maybe I should calculate everything over pixel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take into account that the height of the text is going to be used for every line of text; calculate the vertical size for all lines and base your positions on that:

```
# Half of the remainder of the image height when space for all lines has been reserved:
line_dimensions = [draw.textsize(line, font=font) for line in para]
offset = (MAX_H - sum(h for w, h in line_dimensions)) // 2

current_h = offset
for line, (w, h) in zip(para, line_dimensions):
    draw.text(((MAX_W - w) // 2, current_h), line, font=font)
    current_h += h
```

Here `line_dimensions` is a list of `(width, height)` tuples for each line in the paragraph. The total height is then taken from that (with the `sum()` and generator expression), and we use that to calculate an initial offset.